# Silverlight Unit Test - Localization

Tags: silverlight-4.0, tdd

I am working on Silverlight application and got stuck with one issue related to unit test.
Putpose of this unit test is to test localization.

Bydefault culture is English and i want to test for french culture. 
I tried with setting culture and UI culture and DeploymentItem attribute. But no success.

Here is my test

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
[TestClass]
public class SampleTest
{

   [TestMethod]
   [DeploymentItem(@"Bin\fr", "fr")]
   public void Test Method()
   {
            SetSpecificCurture(false);
            string test = EngineAnomaliesViewStrings.Identifier;
            Note: [EngineAnomaliesViewStrings is my resource file]  

            Assert.AreEqual("Some French Test", test);   
   }

   private void setSpecificCurture(Boolean isUkLable)
        {
            CurrentUserLogged.Details.IsUKLanguage = isUkLable;

            string culture = isUkLable ? "en" : "fr";
            string dateFormat = isUkLable ? "MM/dd/yyyy" : "dd/MM/yyyy";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = dateFormat;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = dateFormat;

        }
```

Even through setting FR culture, always getting english values.

Can anyone have an idea to sovle the issue?

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Answer (score 0):

Mahesh,

Just for the purpose of others to know how we resolved this problem. As we've found out, the solution is to add an AssemblyPart inside the Deployment.Parts node in the AppMenifest.xml file of the Silverlight UnitTest project. (The fr resource file are not included in the UnitTest project xap file by default)

```
<AssemblyPart Source="fr/MyProject.resources.dll" />
```

Thanks.

Dax